# MAC OS Installer "child process exited abnormally"?

Tags: macos, installation, user-permissions, child-process, pkg-file

On MAC OS I am running a installer package in the [Installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer_%28OS_X%29) like as shown below,

```
-pkg "~/Desktop/SubFolder/app.pkg" -target /
```

And I get this error message,

> **Child process exited abnormally**

Any ideas for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you:

- use `-dumplog` parameter of the `installer` utility
- see what you get in syslog
- try to launch `installer` with root privileges (i.e. `sudo`)
- try to launch your package in GUI mode and see if it will be installed (there can be some install check)